# To “travel” inside a house?

Tags: word-usage

I am a native speaker of Spanish, and, when moving inside a big house, which may also have a large garden, we sometimes use the verb “viajar” = “to travel”= “to make a trip” if we need to move over thirty or forty metres. When “viajar” is used in this context, the tone is rather informal, and the word can or cannot have an ironic/emphatic connotation.

Then, assuming that a woman is in a large residence, consider the following sentence:

- *She went from the kitchen to the music room and* travelled/made the trip *twice*.

My questions:

a) Can “to travel” and “to make a trip” also be used in this way in English?

b) Are they formal or informal in this context?

I thank you all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119611/discussion-on-question-by-roberto-to-travel-inside-a-house).

Comment: MODERATOR NOTE: Answers go in the answer box, not the comment box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) Can “to travel” and “to make a trip” also be used in this way in English?

**To travel** is not used for movement inside any building with the possible exception of using a vehicle of some sort. (Wheelchair; forklift truck, etc.)

To **make the** trip can be used to indicate a great distance and/or a tedious journey. It is also possible to use this as a form of emphasis or exaggeration -It is casual/informal.

"That's the tenth time I've had to make the trip up those stairs! If you want anything else, you can get it yourself!" ELU, Greybeard 2021

to **make/take a** trip - "I have to **take a** trip to the toilet/bathroom" - can be used informally - it is informal but it does not indicate the distance, which may be quite short:

From "Oscar Murillo: the build-up of content and information" - Page 34

> during a long-haul flight I'm interrupted only by a trip to the toilet, or by a neighboring passenger asking to exit the row

and

An Ongoing Investigation - Page 327 by Timothy Daniels · 2014

> He poured another and made a quick trip to the bedroom, where he kicked off his shoes and socks and pulled on a pair of slippers.

> b) Are they formal or informal in this context?

Informal.

Answer (score 1):

*Trip* does not necessarily indicate a long distance. You can have a trip to Tibet for the summer, a trip to the market to buy some chicken, or a trip to the toilet after eating some bad chicken.

*Travel* in contrast would be unusual in any local context. If I *travel* for work, it typically means I am going out of the area— flying, or perhaps driving for several hours, in order to reach the work site. I *commute* to my office in the nearby city every morning, I do not *travel* to it. The *business traveler* is a different kind of worker from the *commuter*.

If you want explicitly to draw attention to the distances within a large or spread-out house, I wouldn't suggest either *trip* (which does not necessarily imply distance or difficulty) or *travel*. A *[hike](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hike_1)* or *[trek](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/trek_1)* would be more evocative, or even *[journey](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/journey_1)*, whether employed as a verb or a noun. A *[haul](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/haul_1)* might be suitable if carrying something, although this can connote burden or difficulty rather  than distance.

> She made the trek from the kitchen to the music room twice.

> She hiked from the kitchen to the music room twice.

> She went from the kitchen to the music room twice, each time a journey.

Comment: 'Made the trip' would also be a marked usage within a house. Natural ways of expressing several journeys within a house would use say 'several times a day', 'always', 'constantly'.

Comment: It can be, but I would say only if the spread of the house had been established previously. My house is assuredly neither large nor spread-out, and when I say I have been making constant trips to the kitchen during the pandemic, no one would make that assumption.

Comment: The example sentences are  'She went from the kitchen to the music room and travelled/made the trip twice'. Admittedly an unnatural way of putting things per se, but 'making constant trips' is far more idiomatic than 'made the trip' in a domestic setting.